# Adsense's ad code doesn't work for my blog

Tags: adsense, blogspot

i have google adsense Account which is activated already.

Now, i am going to place an AD on my blog and i added code into my blog but don't know why i am not able to see that AD on my blog

please help me out !!

Here is My Ad Code :

```
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9307704483757505"
     data-ad-slot="2264250676"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you tried. Have you checked a browser's developer tools to see if there are any errors on the page or what network calls are being made to retrieve the ads?

Comment: Hello Ashish & akiraspeirs, Could you please look into my code ? i am still not getting the Result...please